# how to check if element has already been clicked javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm trying to add multiple event listeners a `UL` in javascript.

How can I create a condition to `.preventDefault()` if one of my `.card` elements has already been clicked?

```
const cd = document.getElementById('listDeck')
cd.addEventListener('click', flipFirst, false)


function flipFirst(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
    var firstMove = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
    firstMove.classList.add('open', 'show')
    console.log('first card was clicked')
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener('click', flipFirst);
  }
}

cd.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  if () {
    //condition is true
    //then prevent default
  }   
    var secondMove = document.getElementById(evt.target.id)
    secondMove.classList.add('open', 'show')
    console.log('second card was clicked')
})
```

Comment: Add an attribute to the clicked element onClick. Something like `data-clicked = "true"`. and check for that attribute onClick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution would be to set a property on evt.currentTarget, which refers to the dom node that the handler is on.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it would be to just set a class to the li that was clicked.

```
function flipFirst(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
    var firstMove = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
    firstMove.classList.add('open', 'show', 'wasClicked') // Add class if clicked
    console.log('first card was clicked')
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener('click', flipFirst);
  }
}

cd.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  if (evt.srcElement.classList.contains('wasClicked') == true) { // check if it has the class
    //then prevent default
  }   
    var secondMove = document.getElementById(evt.target.id)
    secondMove.classList.add('open', 'show')
    console.log('second card was clicked')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Or set a boolean variable in javascript

```
const cd = document.getElementById('listDeck')
cd.addEventListener('click', flipFirst, false)
var isBtnClicked = false; // <-- Here is variable declared.

function flipFirst(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        var firstMove = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
        firstMove.classList.add('open', 'show')
        console.log('first card was clicked')
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener('click', flipFirst);
    }
}

cd.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if () {
        //condition is true
        //then prevent default
    }   

     var secondMove = document.getElementById(evt.target.id)
     secondMove.classList.add('open', 'show')
     console.log('second card was clicked')
     isBtnClicked = true; // <--- Here is the variable

})
```